# Google Cloud Shell and Cloud Storage - Permission to access the GCS address is denied

Tags: shell, google-app-engine, nlp, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to set up Google's Natural Language Processing API using Google Cloud Shell and Cloud Storage.

My issue is, I keep getting this error when I point the code at the particular bucket object:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Permission to access the GCS address is denied.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "document.gcs_content_uri",
            "description": "Permission to access the GCS address is denied."
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @requestb.json https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=${NL_
API_KEY}
```

I'm the owner of the Cloud account and have access to all projects. Is there something I'm missing here?

The API call works fine with Cloud Shell if I set the object to 'Public'.

Any help on this would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

I realised I hadn't passed the location of the service account's key file. Like so:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=service-account-key-file
```

I did this by downloading the key from the credentials area, then reuploading it into the Google Cloud Shell command line (it has a nice code editor called 'Orion' that lets you view and edit each uploaded file).

I then followed from step 3 onwards [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/getting-started#set_up_your_project)

I modified the code in step 4 to send the API to an object in a bucket in Google Cloud Storage, like so:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxauth-tokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --data-binary @requestb.json https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=${NL_API_KEY}
```

The above '@requestb.json' is another text file I uploaded to Google Cloud Shell, which contained the following json information:

```
{
  "document":{
    "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
    "gcsContentUri": "gs://<bucket-name>/<object-name>"
  }
}
```

And it worked!

My object was a .txt file containing a sampled BBC News article and returned this response:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "Mosul",
      "type": "LOCATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosul"
      },
      "salience": 0.16690882,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "ir Mo",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "ar Mo",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "of Mo",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "to Mo",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "US",
      "type": "LOCATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States"
      },
      "salience": 0.058336213,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "he",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "y,",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Iraqi",
      "type": "LOCATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq"
      },
      "salience": 0.0219927,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "An Ir",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "ng Ir",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "h, I",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Qusay Hamid Kadhem",
      "type": "PERSON",
      "metadata": {},
      "salience": 0.01995722,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "r, Qusay Hamid Kad",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Qaraqosh",
      "type": "LOCATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakhdida"
      },
      "salience": 0.018237775,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "of Qaraq",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": ".\r\nQaraq",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "AFP",
      "type": "ORGANIZATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agence_France-Presse"
      },
      "salience": 0.0049931784,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "ld ",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "IS",
      "type": "ORGANIZATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_State_of_Iraq_and_the_Levant"
      },
        }
      "salience": 0.0046183467,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "he",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "ut",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Reuters",
      "type": "ORGANIZATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuters"
      },
      "salience": 0.0041254032,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": ".\r\nReut",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Christian",
      "type": "PERSON",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian"
      },
      "salience": 0.0016911785,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "st Christ",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "language": "en"
```

My plan is to now send multiple responses to Big Query and then Data Visualisation as per this great [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/comparing-tweets-about-trump-hillary-with-natural-language-processing-a0064e949666#.44pwbpgxi)